# How do I use Google Charts with mySQL data?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, google-visualization

I'm working on a website that stores information in databases using mysql. I want to display that information using interactive diagrams via google charts. The problem is that I cant figure out how to use the mysql data with google charts. I did some research and found that I need to encode the data in JSON format but I'm not sure as to how I can do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(one method - there are probably many)

Use php to create the JSON strings from your query and pass these to google charts on the client.

(pcode)

```
<?php
$rows = PDO->query( "select col0, col1 from table" );
echo "jsonvar = {";
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
    echo "{" . $row->col0 . "," . $row->col1 . "},";
}
echo "};";

?>
// some call to google charts on the client
gchart.make_a_cool_graph( jsonvar, otherparams,... );
```